# MVC ListboxFor variable in model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, html.listboxfor

I have a listbox as

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDepartment, Model.Departments, 
                 new { @class = "form-control", @style = "height:150px", size = 4,
                 onchange = "DepartmentSelectionChanged(this)" })
```

and in my model

```
 public IEnumerable<string> SelectedDepartment { get; set; }
```

However on returning the view I get an error as

> System.InvalidOperationException: The ViewData item that has the key 
>    'SelectedDepartment' is of type 'System.String[]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

What is wrong ?

How can I correct this ?

Comment: Please add the controller code where you are setting ViewData.SelectedDepartment

Comment: Could you show your controller

Answer (score 0):

The ViewData item that has the key 'SelectedDepartment' is of type 'System.**String**[]' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<**SelectListItem**>'.

It's not the usage of `IEnumerable` / `string[]` that is the issue, but the fact you're passing a set of `string` objects instead of `SelectListItem` objects.

You can easily convert it:

```
List<SelectListItem> selectlistitems = new List<SelectListItem>();

foreach(string mystring in myarray)
{
    selectlistitems.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = mystring, Value = mystring };
}

ViewData["SelectedDepartment"] = selectlistitems;
```

It's even shorter if you use LINQ:

```
ViewData["SelectedDepartment"] = 
        myarray.Select(mystring => new SelectListItem() { Text = mystring, Value = mystring })
            .ToList();
```